# Find string with certain length VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to find a string with exactly 4 characters without spaces within a column. There are more strings in cells. I would like to avoid using formulas.

Comment: VBA has a function called `Len` which will return the length of a given value.  You can use this on a cell, or on parts of cell values or in any number of other ways.  It would help if you could give an example of your input, and show how you would like the output formatted.  Also, please show whatever code you have written to try and perform this action?

Comment: I want to perform this on column wich is basicly a result of an OCR text recognition method created by MODI office module. There is around 90 rows in one column and there is couple of strings within each cell. I want to extract string 4 letters/numbers long within this certain column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming column "A" is the one

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim arr As Variant, arrElem As Variant

    With Worksheets("Strings") '<--| change "Strings" to your actual worksheet name
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ") '<--| change "A"'s to your actual relevant column index
            For Each arrElem In arr
                If Len(arrElem) = 4 Then MsgBox arrElem
            Next arrElem
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @eurano Please mark the answer as correct to help others looking for the answer to the same question.

Comment: eurano, you're welcome. and .... yes, as also @SkipIntro pointed out, please mark answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as you have a specific string, four characters long, you need to find in cells. This one will do that. Just replace `"test"` with whatever your string is, and change the column if necessary:

```
Sub findCells()
Dim rCells() As Variant
Dim str As String
Dim col As Integer

str = "test" ' replace this with the text you want to find
col = 1 ' to search Column A

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, col), str) Then
        ' Match found, add code here to do
        ' whatever you need.
        Debug.Print "Match found in cell: " & Cells(i, col).Address
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```